# Can't add cookie options

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I am currently creating a cookie, where I am storing my refresh token. The cookie is working perfectly fine, until I try to add a path or expiration time.

This is working perfectly fine. The cookie is created and shown in Postman or my browser.

```
CookieOptions cookie = new CookieOptions();
Response.Cookies.Append("Authentication", _refreshTokenObj.Refreshtoken, cookie);
```

This is not working. I can't create the cookie or see it in Postman or my browser.

```
CookieOptions cookie = new CookieOptions()
{
    Path = "/RefreshToken",
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4),
    IsEssential = true
};
Response.Cookies.Append("Authentication", _refreshTokenObj.Refreshtoken, cookie);
```

**EDIT:**
After some test, i found out, there is just the issue to set the path option. Expiration time is working.